# Mottie Keyboard: Change focus when input field equals maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I will make input automatically change focus to next input if input field equals maxlength. The input field is integrated with Mottie Keyboard. Is it possible to do this?

Here's DEMO : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MK947/4434/)

If Virtual Keyboard is not used, it's easy to use this code:

```
$("input").bind("input", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ( $this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr("maxlength"),10) )
                $this.next("input").focus();
        },0);
    });
```

When I combine script given above with Mottie Keyboard, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are not binding any event to the input field. Also, if the time is 0, then no need to call `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: can you give me jsfiddle demo? @Samir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you also opened the [issue](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/482) in the repository?

To summarize my response there, use the `change` callback with the `switchInput` API function to accomplish what you need ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bwpc31nj/)):

HTML (example)

```
<input type="text" /> <!-- max len = 3 -->
<input type="text" /> <!-- max len = 3 -->
<input class="last" type="text" /> <!-- max len = 4 -->
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  $("input").keyboard({
    position: {
      // position under center input
      of: $("input:eq(1)"),
      // move down 12px; not sure why it doesn't line up
      my: 'center top+12',
      at: 'center top'
    },
    enterNavigation: true,
    maxLength: 4,
    layout: 'num',
    autoAccept: true,
    usePreview: false,
    change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
      var len = keyboard.$el.hasClass("last") ? 4 : 3;
      if (keyboard.$el.val().length >= len) {
        // switchInput( goToNext, isAccepted );
        keyboard.switchInput(true, true);
      } else if (keyboard.$el.val() === "" && keyboard.last.key === "bksp") {
        // go to previous if user hits backspace on an empty input
        keyboard.switchInput(false, true);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I've [updated your demo as well](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/4437/)... I had to tweak a few things to get it to work as expected.

Comment: Ok thank you bro, and sorry for duplicate question :)

Comment: can't use alwaysOpen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this, Hope this will work

```
$("input").on("focus blur", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val(),
        maxLength = $this.attr("maxlength");
    if ( value.length >= maxLength  ){
       $this.next("input").focus();
    }      
});
```

Comment: Try using the `focus blur` methods.

Comment: i've change to `focus & blur` but it same

Comment: Is this for any mobile device? Or for desktop web application?

Comment: desktop web bro, you can see my jsfiddle in my answer to example